# Xubuntu 16.04 ctrl + a shortcut not working (to mark all text)

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys

The shortcut ctrl + a should work system wide to mark all text in a document. 
It does not work on my lenovo x220 laptop running xubuntu 16.04. 
I tried firefox, libreoffice and gedit to test this behavior.

Under terminal I tried the command "showkey -a". I get responses for other ctrl + key combinations and a corresponding asci code is shown. For ctrl + a there is no corresponding asci code. I tested this behavior on the integrated keyboard as well as on an external keyboard connected via usb. 
If I mark a text in firefox the underlined text turn from blue to grey, so there is some kind of key response... What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you have mapped ctrl+a as a keyboard shortcut to something else?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had mapped right ctrl + alt + a to enter keepass password, which worked, but seems to have messed up the ctrl + a shortcut somehow. It was saved as ctrl + ae ('a' and 'e' were pictured as a combined symbol). Removing the keepass mapping has restored the old mark all functionality.

Comment: Please add that as an answer to your question!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tip about the wrong mapping, Charles Green. I had mapped right ctrl + alt + a to enter keepass password, which worked, but seems to have messed up the ctrl + a shortcut somehow. It was saved as ctrl + ae ('a' and 'e' were pictured as a combined symbol). Removing the keepass mapping has restored the old mark all functionality.

Comment: How did you find out? By checking in xfconf at "xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts"? I have the same problem, but don't see any mapping involving an "a"...

Comment: I'm sorry, that was two years ago, please post here as soon as you find out. I had forgotten about having that problem or even having a stackexchange account.