# Reset one specific keymapping in Xfce (Ctrl-A does not work)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xubuntu, xfce

#### Shortly:

In Xfce, how to list and remove all existing non-default mappings associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> ?

#### Details

I installed Xubuntu 18.04.03 recently, and restored part of the `~/.config/xfce4/` directory from a previous backup.

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> does nothing but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

- on text, it does not select everything;
- in terminal, it does not go to the beginning of the line;
- in tmux, I have it as prefix key, but does nothing;
- running `xev -event keyboard`, I see the "Press" and "Release" of "Control_L", but in between, no "A", just this:

  ```
  KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
      keys:  39  0   0   0   32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  ```

In TTY, it works as expected.

Someone on Askubuntu already [encountered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977052/xubuntu-16-04-ctrl-a-shortcut-not-working-to-mark-all-text) this problem, but in my case I can't find a mapping similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> either graphically in Xfconf "xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts" or by grepping `;a` in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`.

How to get a functional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> again?

Comment: What do you get with `xev | grep -E -A3 "^KeyPress"`? What happens with a new user?

Comment: It works in a new user as well... I get all KeyPress for Control_L, and other letters. I might have to purge this old config... Will try a reset of `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`.

Comment: Probably a diff of the two xml files will help.

Comment: Only if that's the relevant file!